# have to / must / should / ought as applied to inanimate objects

Tags: word-choice

have to
must
should
ought

I found a lot of examples with explanations on using this words applying to people, but not to inanimate objects. In the case of inanimate objects, such explanations as “obligatory”, “moral correctness”, “advise” etc. does not work.
What the verbs should be used in the next sentences?

*The car _______  turn when the driver turns the steering wheel.*
*The car _______ not start moving spontaneously.*
*The (computer) program _______ solve the equation.*
*If an error occures, the program _______ indicate a message.*

I think, different variants are possible and they have different meanings.

Comment: To take one example, 'The car must turn when the driver turns the steering wheel.' If this follows 'We've carried out the service very thoroughly.', the usage is that of epistemic modality: 'There's no way [as far as I'm concerned] that the car won't turn!' But if the preceding sentence was 'You've got to sort this out!', the modality shown in  'The car must turn when the driver turns the steering wheel.' is deontic. A ...

Comment: fuller definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) is: 'The sentence containing the deontic modal generally indicates [here, points to, in the preceding sentence] some action that would change the world so that it becomes closer to the standard or ideal.' Consider this as a paraphrase of 'You must make sure that the car turns when ...'.

Comment: -1 *For the parade to attract the largest crowd, the sun (___)  be  out.* Insert  any of your four words for a good English sentence.

Comment: The verb *should* works in all your sentences.

Comment: @Peter Shor, what about the other verbs?

Answer (score 2):

*Must* and *should* are English modal auxiliary verbs.  The other English modal auxiliary verbs are *may, might, shall, will, would, can,* and *could*.

*Ought (to)* and *have to* are periphrastic modal auxiliary idioms. Some others include *be likely (to), be able to, be required (to), be possible (that)*, and *be expected*.

**All** modals, whether periphrastic or not, have **two** kinds of meaning: ***Deontic*** and ***Epistemic***.

**Deontic** modality has to do with obligations, permissions, and affordances conceived in a stratified social network:

- *She **may** go to the dance with you, but she **has to** be back by midnight.*

Deontic modality doesn't apply to things, outside metaphors. Things need **Epistemic** modality,
which has to do with possibility and necessity, from logical and practical/mechanical causes:

- *The ball **may** pass through either gate, but it **has to** go in this hole in order to score.*

Epistemic *must* and *have to* mean 'necessary', but deontically they mean 'obligated to'.

Epistemic *should* and *ought to* mean 'likely, probable'; deontically they mean 'morally obliged to'.

Epistemic *can, could, may,* and *might* refer to possibilities; deontically they refer to permissions.

Comment: +1 Another useful post. While I'm here and we're talking modality, are there any modal words/phrases used as determiners?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Not really, but in a way you can think of modals, negatives, and quantifiers as being Operators (functors with Superpowers like Binding and Polarity) and quantifiers are the ones that act as determiners.